# normal distributed probability for corner of path

Tags: python, numpy, normal-distribution

I am working on assgining the high probability at the center of path and low at the edge of path.

[image]

This is img of my current result. However, the probability values are overlap at the corner.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

gridPath = "resources/myGrid3/"
pathFile = "pathNorm.csv"
myFile = "myPath8.csv"

pathDf = pd.read_csv(gridPath + pathFile)
myDf = pd.read_csv(gridPath + myFile)

pathDf = pathDf.drop_duplicates(["x"])

maxXGrid = pathDf.x.max() + 2
maxYGrid = pathDf.y.max() + 2
minXGrid = pathDf.x.min() - 2
minYGrid = pathDf.y.min() - 2

dx1 = 0.1
dx2 = 0.1

x1 = np.arange(minXGrid, maxXGrid, dx1)
x2 = np.arange(minYGrid, maxYGrid, dx2)
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(x1, x2)
X = np.column_stack((X1.flatten(), X2.flatten()))

sigma_p = 0.7

path_pdf = np.sum((1 / (np.sqrt(2 * np.pi) * sigma_p)) * np.exp(-0.5 * (1 / (sigma_p ** 2)) * (np.sqrt((X1[:, :, None] - pathDf.x.values) ** 2 + (X2[:, :, None] - pathDf.y.values) ** 2)) ** 2), axis=2)
path_pdf /= np.sum(path_pdf)  # Normalize the pdf

fig = plt.figure(3)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
f = ax.pcolor(X1, X2, path_pdf)
plt.colorbar(f, ax=ax)
ax.scatter(myDf.x, myDf.y, color='white', label="Path", marker="x", s=0.1)
ax.set_xlabel('$x$-axis (m)', fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel('$y$-axis (m)', fontsize=12)
ax.scatter(pathDf.x.iloc[0], pathDf.y.iloc[0], c='b', marker='o', label='Start')
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_title('PDF of Path')
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

I am assuming that at the corner, values add up to close points and increase the value, but I am not sure how I should handle this. I want to have all points have same probability values.

Is there way to avoid overlaping of probability values at the corner?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of code from question:

```
path_pdf = np.sum((1 / (np.sqrt(2 * np.pi) * sigma_p)) * np.exp(-0.5 * (1 / (sigma_p ** 2)) * (np.sqrt((X1[:, :, None] - pathDf.x.values) ** 2 + (X2[:, :, None] - pathDf.y.values) ** 2)) ** 2), axis=2)
path_pdf /= np.sum(path_pdf)  # Normalize the pdf
```

Try this:

```
path_pdf = np.max((1 / (np.sqrt(2 * np.pi) * sigma_p)) * np.exp(-0.5 * (1 / (sigma_p ** 2)) * (np.sqrt((X1[:, :, None] - pathNormDf.x.values) ** 2 + (X2[:, :, None] - pathNormDf.y.values) ** 2)) ** 2), axis=2)
path_pdf /= np.sum(path_pdf)  # Normalize the pdf
```

It still has some issue at the corner (not fully add the probability). But, it is more straight line and no overlaps of values

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for the overlap of probability values at the corner of the path could be due to the choice of kernel bandwidth (sigma_p in your code). If the bandwidth is too large, then the contributions from nearby points along the path may overlap and result in higher probability values at the corner.

To avoid this issue, you could try reducing the value of sigma_p to decrease the amount of overlap between the contributions from nearby points. This should result in a more uniform distribution of probability values along the path.

Comment: yes that could be the easy way. but I want to fit the distribution along the path which is the white line on the figure.