# How to reduce the size of only center part to normal distribution?

Tags: python, numpy, normal-distribution

This is follow up question for solving my previous question.

[normal distributed probability for corner of path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76840909/normal-distributed-probability-for-corner-of-path)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

gridPath = "resources/myGrid3/"
pathNormFile = "pathNorm2.csv"
myFile = "myPath8.csv"

pathNormDf = pd.read_csv(gridPath + pathNormFile)
myDf = pd.read_csv(gridPath + myFile)

pathNormDf = pathNormDf.drop_duplicates(["x"])

maxXGrid = pathNormDf.x.max() + 1
maxYGrid = pathNormDf.y.max() + 1
minXGrid = pathNormDf.x.min() - 1
minYGrid = pathNormDf.y.min() - 1

dx1 = 0.1
dx2 = 0.1

x1 = np.arange(minXGrid, maxXGrid, dx1)
x2 = np.arange(minYGrid, maxYGrid, dx2)
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(x1, x2)
X = np.column_stack((X1.flatten(), X2.flatten()))

sigma_p = 0.7

path_pdf = (1 / (np.sqrt(2 * np.pi) * sigma_p)) * np.exp(-0.5 * (1 / (sigma_p ** 2)) * (np.sqrt((X1 - pathNormDf.x[0]) ** 2 + (X2 - pathNormDf.y[0]) ** 2)) ** 2)

fig = plt.figure(3)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
f = ax.pcolor(X1, X2, path_pdf)
plt.colorbar(f, ax=ax)

ax.scatter(myDf.x, myDf.y, color='white', label="Path", marker="x", s=0.1)
ax.scatter(pathNormDf.x, pathNormDf.y, color='black', label="Path", marker="x", s=0.1)

ax.set_xlabel('$x$-axis (m)', fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel('$y$-axis (m)', fontsize=12)
ax.scatter(pathNormDf.x.iloc[0], pathNormDf.y.iloc[0], c='b', marker='o', label='Start')
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_title('PDF of Path')
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

When I run code aboce, result looks like this.

[image]

sigma_p decide the size of the noraml distribution. (this case, size of circle).

What I want is keep the overall size of distribution but only reduce the size of yellow part.

Is it possible to manipulate the probability with normal distribution equation?

Comment: If you want to change the center of the distribution (by contracting it, and increasing the magnitude near the center), while leaving the rest unchanged, then you will no longer have a normal distribution.  So you need to decide what sort of distribution you want, and work out the math for it.

Comment: Also there is no "overall size of distribution", the normal distribution extends from -Inf to +Inf, there is no limit between the purple and green in reality. That's just our brain faking one for us.